# have vs will have

Tags: grammaticality

May I know which one of the following is grammatical?

> I won't take your time anymore as you **have** another meeting later
>
> I
>   won't take your time anymore as you **will have** another meeting later

Comment: 'Any more' meaning '‘no longer’ or ‘in the past but not now' is usually **two words**, but can be written as one word, especially in American English.

Answer (score 0):

You should use *simple present* (first sentence) in case you want to state a **fact**.
You should use *simple future* (second sentence) if you want to make an **assumption**.

So depending on what you are trying to say both senteces are correct.

Comment: The second one can also be a boss talking...